# What softwares are used to produce this video?

Tags: video

https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=732070063514894&set=vb.410157642372806&type=3&theater

I have no experience with any video production softwares but I need to do something similar to that video. are there any specific softwares that can produce something like this?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13082/what-are-motion-graphics/).  We've had a number of questions very similar to this in the past, so I'm attempting to make a catch-all answer that should be able to cover this kind of situation.  Please let me know if you find it helpful or if it leaves you with any additional questions.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some kind of 2D animation program to do this. [After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) is one possibilty.

However, these are advanced animations. Without any experience, it will take quite some time to learn how to do this and achieve similar effects. If you're not willing to put some time in it, you don't even have to start ...

Answer (score 1):

After effects could be a good place to start, and I'd say with little experience, if you did go down that route, would be to look for templates. Search around for things like "infographics templates" or "motion charts" or "animated graph" charts templates or tutorials, just to point you in the right direction but those are just words off the top of my head.

--
update: with a 2 minute google search i found this, albeit far simpler tutorial on animating graphs in powerpoint http://www.presentation-process.com/powerpoint-chart-animation.html#.VHIiIoepQVk and here's one that's a bit less colourful http://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/pptblog/create-the-effect-of-a-line-drawing-itself/ . basically google is probably your best friend at this point, with keywords like graph, animation, presentation, creator.